# How to select specific column from table in php from user input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using php-mysql to query from my database and show it in browser. I am also using FORM input to get variable from user (eg: startdate/enddate/ingress). All of which is working fine.

Now I want to implement checkbox in my forms, so that user can get/query only desired columns according to his requirement. How can I do that ?

Comment: You could handle column visibility in the css

Comment: But I want to get the data from user 1st (on which column to show), not setting it before hand from css

Comment: There's no 'beforehand' about it.